Is it reasonable, and within site rules, to have a blanket insistence on going by Wikipedia?
From this question, I got a comment which I frequently see from this moderator:

"both groups are visibly distinct from each other" This contradicts every other source I've read. What research have you done into pre-colonial relations? What is wrong with Wikipeda? You cite Wikipedia, but the conclusions you draw are markedly different. I think all the questions you asked are address in the background section of that article. –
MCW
♦

Now, wikipedia is a wonderful resource, don't get me wrong.  There is a lot of expertise there.  But let me know quote from my answer to this comment:

I wonder at your insistence on filtering all questions through wikipedia. Wikipedia is not the end all and be all of knowledge sources, especially not on controversial subjects. For example, the page on Salafism was unusable for years as pro-Salafists and anti-Salafits duked it out. The page on Thugs in India has had extensive rewrites over time. I am unsure that your role as a moderator involves pushing requirements that are not, to my knowledge, part of the formal rules of this forum.

So, what is the formal position of this site, as opposed to this particular moderator's insistence?
An insistence which is justified in many cases.  But should we take for granted that wikipedia is authoritative in all cases?  And especially, on subjects that are controversial in the political, social and historical sciences.   Which is what we are dealing with here.  To my knowledge, this deference is not accorded to Wikipedia in academia, for example.
While I did not cite wikipedia, I did cite an article from Le Monde Diplomatique on the "contra" position to my question, that the Belgians were principally to blame for the animosity.

I'm perhaps more permissive that a lot of folks here, but maybe that means the following could be considered a bare minimum?
For me the principle is, if I can find a Wikipedia page on the asked subject, and it seems to answer the question with no further analysis or research needed, its probably too simple a question. We aren't really adding any benefit to the world by just excerpting bits of existing Wikipedia pages.
Someone who took a few minutes to read the obvious WP page themself would never have had to ask the question. Or they might have a follow-on question, which they should have just asked in the first place after reading, rather than come up with on the spot in the comments after the obvious answer was pointed out.
If they have read it, but it didn't answer their question, that information should be in their initial question. We shouldn't have to drag it out of them with hours of our own work in the comments.
I used to have similar feelings about doing a simple Google search (like if the digest from the first 3 hits answers the question without having to click on a link), but frankly getting factual information out of Google lately takes a lot more skill than it used to.
For me the other important thing about research is if there's stuff you already know, you should tell us that with references. That way we don't have 100 smart people wasting an hour of their lives (100 valuable history man hours lost) figuring out something you could have just told them all with 2 minutes work.
Now sometimes knowing enough already about the history of the matter from years of other research to know where in our handy-dandy online encyclopedia to look, or what jargon to use with Google, makes it easy for me to look up, but no so easy for someone else. That's where I think perhaps where we ought to be a bit more forgiving sometimes. But also if that's the case, we probably ought to be giving a very newbie-friendly answer too.

Thanks for the answer.  First, I did read quickly some of the wikipedia entries, but they are quite long in general and I missed that the Hutu-Tutsi relations were embedded in the backgrounder for the genocide.  I searched for "Hutu Tutsi relations wiki" and found no such page.  There is no mention of ethnic friction @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rwanda#Demographics  Having now added the backgrounder, it doesn't answer the question, except that it leans towards putting more paragraphs on Belgian actions than on the uburetwa system.

I also find posts by that particular moderator are generally more conflictual and unfriendly than they need to be.  And not just on my posts.  If, like you say, the primary point of asking about wikipedia is to establish a baseline of knowledge from the OP - which I agree with if explained reasonably - then that can be asked a lot more neutrally than they tend to do.

No, Wikipedia is not the be all end all of knowledge sources. But if you look through the decade+ of answers on this site, you'll see that it is almost always the resource that answers cite (and frequently/unfortunately, the only resource cited).
To get ahead of the inevitable back and forth where a question gets a Wikipedia answer and the asker coughs up a reason that it's insufficient, we skip directly to that point by asking that the question include that reason up front.
If an asker has consulted other sources - especially other easy to find sources - it's also expected that they explain why those sources are not sufficient to answer their question. Wikipedia is neither more nor less privileged, just far more likely to appear in an answer than any other single source.

Excellent question, thank you for raising it in meta.
The simple answer is that I'm not pushing Wikipedia, I'm pushing basic research.  I've got an automated comment that gets attached to any question that lacks the basic courtesy of doing some research before asking.  In these cases "Wikipedia" is merely a label for standard references such as  "Wikipedia or Google, or searching the archives of H:SE". There are limits to the length of comments and I've revised that automated comment multiple times over the years to try to find a compromise between brevity and specificity. I'm happy to entertain suggestions for revised wording.
The question you reference includes basic research, and I normally would not step in.   But the question asked in the title is answered by the Wikipedia section that I cite.   I think the comment applies - Why doesn't the answer in Wikipedia suffice?
A question on H:SE is a request that I expert effort to find an answer. Basic courtesy (and SE convention throughout the exchange) require that OP attempt to answer the question first, and ask only when the answer cannot be found through standard references.
I'm strongly disinclined to go off and search for an answer if the question reveals that OP has already read the answer and refused to accept it but won't explain why.  In my experience that general pattern is strongly associated with questions that will not be answered - usually because it is actually a request for a discussion. Those are valid, but are a bad fit for H:SE.
Most SE site suggests that new users read questions for a couple of days before asking, to get a feel for the culture.  Leaving that comment is a signal that H:SE expects preliminary research.  If we don't signal that expectation, new users will not be aware of that expectation, which is an incentive to violating the expectation.
As I said, I'm completely open to revisions to language or technique, so long as they encourage the kind of site we want.

Do you mean this section:  The ethnic identities of the Hutu and Tutsi were reshaped and mythologized by the colonizers..  This is precisely the type of stuff I am uncertain is really the case.  You claim that's authoritative, I claim that looks like, possibly, not certainly, a statement that is questionable.  Please cite, for more clarity, which sections of the article you use to claim that "all my questions were already answered".

On top of that, while I did not cite wikipedia, I did cite an article - Le Monde Diplomatique - putting forward exactly the "all Belgium's fault" viewpoint, making your objection that I did not bother understanding the basic research rather bizarre.  Last, many of us will have some basic understanding of some subjects and will not have to scrutinize every inch of a wikipedia page to ask about it.
